# YouCompleteMe configuration problems

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete

I'm running Ubuntu and installed YouCompleteMe via vundle.

I'm having the same issues as in this thread
[Vim YouCompleteMe configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264047/vim-youcompleteme-configuration) in that youcompleteme seems to be working, but only autocompletes with only shows words in the current file - however, the solutions in there didn't work for me.

When I used run_tests.sh, it was telling me flake8 was missing, so I installed that, then it complained about nose so I installed that. Now I'm seeing the errors

ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named hamcrest)
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named mock)
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named mock)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to run these tests, but if you want to anyway:

```
[sudo] pip install PyHamcrest mock webtest
```